# How can i check two fileds for order by in kohana query builder

Tags: php, mysql, query-builder

How can i order by two fields in kohana query builder

Eg:- I have two fields of first name and date

I need to order by in single query selection.

Comment: If anyone known means Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

Please [read](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder) this. As they have mentioned Multiple order_by() methods can be used to add additional sorting capability.For eg. please try as below:

```
$query = DB::select()->from(`users`)->order_by(`first_name`, `DESC`)->order_by(`date`, `DESC`);
```